# How to capture current video screen or thumbnail with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Hi i want to capture the current video screen and display the result below.

Even i have reference javascript code here https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GC0Z7WOPB15I though i'm not getting any help to convert it into `vue` in the form of working code.

**Question:** i want same(https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GC0Z7WOPB15I) working code for vue but for single thumbnail

Due to lack of `vuejs` knowledge i'm not able to display the captured image at the required place

**Tried Method 1:**

```js
const app = new Vue({
     el:'#app',
     data(){
       return {
          hello:'world'
       }
   },
   methods:{
      capture(){
             alert('captured called');
             let videoCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
             
         let video = document.getElementById('video')

        videoCanvas.height = video.height;
        videoCanvas.width = video.width;
        videoCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
        var snapshot = videoCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');

        var img = new Image();
        
        img.onload = function () {
          document.body.appendChild(this);
        };
        
        img.src = snapshot;
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">

   <video id="video" controls="controls">
      <source        src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></source>
   </video>
   
   <button @click="capture()">Play and Capture</button>
   
   
   <div>------------------Show captured thumbnail below -----------------</div>

    <img src=""/>
   
</div>
```

Even i tried to convert this code https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GC0Z7WOPB15I to https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/Pojrzax  not working

If any of the approach(or solutions among 2) works that would be fine for me

**Tried Method 2:**

```js
const app = new Vue({
     el:'#app',
      data() {
    return {
     canvas:''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    capture(video, scaleFactor) {
        if(scaleFactor == null){
            scaleFactor = 1;
        }
        var cx =0;
        var cy=0;
        
        var w = video.videoWidth * scaleFactor;
        var h = video.videoHeight * scaleFactor;
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width  = w * 2;
            canvas.height = h * 0.5;
            
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(video, cx, cy, 50, 50);
            ctx.font = '14pt, sans-serif';
            
        return canvas;
    } ,

      displayThumbnail(){
            let video = document.querySelector(`#video`);
            console.log('video',video);
            let scaleFactor = 0.25;
            this.canvas = this.capture(video, scaleFactor);
            console.log('this.canvas',this.canvas);
       }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>



  <div id="app">

   <video id="video" controls="controls">
      <source        src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></source>
   </video>
    
    <button @click="displayThumbnail()"> Capture</button>
    
   <div>----------------------- show captured thumbnail below -----------------------------------</div>
    
<div id="output" style="display: inline-block; top: 4px; position: relative ;border: dotted 1px #ccc; padding: 2px;width:100%" v-html="canvas"></div>
  
  </div>
```

Please help me thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 2):

When you try for `Tried Method 1` first approach you will end up with error

> Error in v-on handler: "SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL'
> on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

- For security reasons, your local drive is declared to be
  "other-domain" and will taint the canvas.
- Seems like you are using an image from a URL that has not set correct
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin header and hence the issue.. You can
  fetch that image from your server and get it from your server to
  avoid CORS issues

I created an example with `Tried Method 2` approach for generating thumbnail from video.

***Step 1:*** Create `HTML` template

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <video id="video" controls="controls">
      <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" /></video
    ><br />
    <button @click="capture()">Play and Capture</button>
    <div>------------------Show captured thumbnail below -----------------</div>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>
```

***Step 2:*** Create `capture` method

```
capture() {
   let videoCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
   let video = document.getElementById("video");
   videoCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
},
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-lamport-b1cvf)

> Updated the answer for generating multiple thumbnails,

***Step 1:*** create `html` template

```
<div id="app">
  <video id="video" controls="controls">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" />
  </video><br />
  <button @click="capture()">Play and Capture</button>&nbsp;
  <button @click="reset()">Reset</button>
  <div>------------------Show captured thumbnail below -----------------</div>
  <div id="output"></div>
</div>
```

***Step 2:*** `methods` for generating multiple thumbnails

```
 capture() {
  var video = document.getElementById("video");
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  var canvas = this.createThumbnail(video, this.scaleFactor);
  canvas.onclick = function () {
    window.open(this.toDataURL());
  };
  this.listThumbnails.unshift(canvas);
  output.innerHTML = "";
  this.listThumbnails.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item) {
      output.appendChild(item);
    }
  });
},
createThumbnail(video, scaleFactor) {
  if (scaleFactor == null) {
    scaleFactor = 1;
  }
  var w = video.videoWidth * scaleFactor;
  var h = video.videoHeight * scaleFactor;
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.style.margin = "5px";
  canvas.width = w;
  canvas.height = h;

  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
  return canvas;
},
reset() {
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  output.innerHTML = "";
  this.listThumbnails = [];
}
```

[Multiple Thumbnail Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-ives-bxhmf)

Comment: your answer works perfectly !!! great

Comment: could you please show me how to do for multiple thumbnails, bounty i will definitely award to you only

Comment: @EaBengaluru I updated the answer and added multiple thumbnails generation with working demo link. Kindly check and let me know.

Comment: great !! it works

Comment: instead of append can't we use `v-for=""`

Answer (score 1):

You need a new variable within your data section (below `hello:`) lets call it `imgSrc: null`.

`var snapshot = videoCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');` should be replaced with `this.imgSrc = videoCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');` everything below including `img.src = snapshot;` could be deleted.

Now you can use data binding for your HTML element.

```
<img :src="imgSrc" v-if="imgSrc" />
```

```js
const app = new Vue({
     el:'#app',
     data(){
       return {
          hello:'world',
          imgSrc: null,
       }
   },
   methods:{
      capture(){
             alert('captured called');
             let videoCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
             
         let video = document.getElementById('video')

        videoCanvas.height = video.height;
        videoCanvas.width = video.width;
        videoCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
        this.imgSrc = videoCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">

   <video id="video" controls="controls">
      <source        src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></source>
   </video>
   
   <button @click="capture()">Play and Capture</button>
   
   
   <div>------------------Show captured thumbnail below -----------------</div>

    <img :src="imgSrc" v-if="imgSrc" />
   
</div>
```

Comment: ok looks great but please produce a snippet or https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://codepen.io/

Comment: Okay, there you go.

Comment: broken image is showing could you please check that once

Comment: hey @iPaat here is one of the working code but i don't know how to convert it to `vue` with only one thumbnail no need to append

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GC0TZE2IGLDP

if you colud help me i will definitely respect your answer