# Can we add a video as a thumbnails before the video start (i am using laravel and Vue.js )?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, video.js

Hi i already have the video to play and the part i want to display, i just want to display it before the video starts, with a single image it works great (for that i use video-js and i put the image in poster) for the video it does not work any suggestion thank you.
i tried to put the video url in the poster but still nothings.

**in html part as i said i am using vue.js**

```
  <video ref="videoPlayer"
                                       :options="videoOptions"
                                       id="video-js"
                                       class="mx-0 px-0 overflow-hidden video-js embed-responsive-item"
                                       v-on:pause="onVideoPause"
                                       crossOrigin="anonymous"
                                       style="object-fit: fill"
                                       :muted="isMuted"
                                >
                                </video>
```

**javascript part**

```
this.player = videojs('video-js', {
                            poster: this.thumbnail,
                            autoplay: response.data.data[0].preferences && (response.data.data[0].preferences.autoplay === 1),
                            preload: true,
                            controls: true,
                            controlBar: {
                                fullscreenToggle: response.data.data[0].preferences && (response.data.data[0].preferences.allow_fullscreen === 1),
                                volumePanel: response.data.data[0].preferences && (response.data.data[0].preferences.volume === 1),
                            },
                            sources: [{
                                src: response.data.data[0].video,
                                type: 'video/mp4',
                            }]
                        });
```

thank you for your answer.

Comment: please check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69444144/how-to-capture-current-video-screen-or-thumbnail-with-vuejs

Comment: it's not the same question he want to take a picture of part of the video for me i already did that without any probleme now i want to do the same with a video like i have the video and i want to play her before the video start like youtube for exemple when you hover the video it will show you a preview

Comment: The question isn't very clear. You want a different video as a poster image?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution i found is to convert the video that we want to use as a thumbnails to a gif and then we can use it in a poster well it worked for me :D